# Python declare winner using dictionary and loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, vote

This is the output of the code I am trying to write. I have seen this done for C++, but not python with a dictionary. The key here is the dictionary is not optional. I need to use it to fulfill the assignment.

```
ID  Candidate           Votes Received      % of Total Vote
1   Johnson             5000                55.55
2   Miller              4000                44.44
Total 9000 
and the winner is Johnson!
```

I need to use a dictionary and a loop to create this. However, I am stuck on 3 points. 
1.The percent- current code returns the percent before it has the whole total ex: first candidate always has 100%. 
2. Declare a winner- code finds the max votes and returns the number value but I need it to return the name. 
3. How to format the dictionary values so it lines up under the header. I don't think is possible, but it must be a requirement to use a dictionary for a reason. I am thinking I need to make a copy of the dictionary and format that?
Here is what I have so far:

```
totalVotes=[]
dct = {}
i = 1
while(True):
    name = input('Please enter a name: ')
    if name == '':

        break
    votes = input('Please enter vote total for canidate: ')
    totalVotes.append(votes)
    totalVotesInt= map(int, totalVotes)
    total = sum(totalVotesInt)
    dct[i] = {name,votes,int(votes)/total*100}
    i += 1
header='{:>0}{:>10}{:>10}{:>20}'.format('ID','Name','Votes','% of Total Vote')
print(header)    
print("\n".join("{}\t{}".format(key, value) for key, value in dct.items()))
print('Total '+str(total))
print('The Winner of the Election is '+max(totalVotes))
```

Which returns:

```
    Please enter a name: Smith
    Please enter vote total for canidate: 100
    Please enter a name: Frieda
    Please enter vote total for canidate: 200
    Please enter a name: West
    Please enter vote total for canidate: 10
    Please enter a name: 
    ID      Name     Votes     % of Total Vote
    1   {'Smith', '100', 100.0}
    2   {'Frieda', 66.66666666666666, '200'}
    3   {3.225806451612903, '10', 'West'}
    Total 310
    The Winner of the Election is 200
```

Comment: check the code I wrote. PS-it is written in Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added very little changes to your code to make it work:

I have mentioned the changes as comments in the code.

*Edit:* It's more efficient to use objects for each candidate if you require scaling in the future.

```
totalVotes=[]
dct = {}
i = 1
while(True):
    name = input('Please enter a name: ')
    if name == '':

        break
    votes = input('Please enter vote total for canidate: ')
    totalVotes.append(votes)
    totalVotesInt= map(int, totalVotes)
    total = sum(totalVotesInt)
    # I change it to a list so it's much easier to append to it later
    dct[i] = list((name,int(votes)))   
    i += 1

# I calculate the total percent of votes in the end and append to the candidate

maxVal = 0
for i in range(1, len(dct) + 1):
    if dct[i][1] > maxVal:
        maxInd = i
    dct[i].append(int((dct[i][len(dct[i]) - 1]) / total * 100))

header='{:>0}{:>10}{:>10}{:>20}'.format('ID','Name','Votes','% of Total Vote')
print(dct)
print(header)    
print("\n".join("{}\t{}".format(key, value) for key, value in dct.items()))
print('Total '+str(total))
print('The Winner of the Election is '+ dct[maxInd][0]))
```

Comment: Thanks @R.p.T, it looks like this one is bringing back the last entry. I think this is because the maxVal is evaluating the keys and not the votes?

Comment: Yes, if you notice, in the for loop when the code adds the percentage of votes for each candidate (I hope the reason I do this in a separate section after getting all the votes first, is clear t you), I calculate the index in the dictionary that has the max number of votes and store the index in `maxInd`. Now that I have the index, I just print out the `name` of the candidate at index `maxInd` in the dictionary

Comment: since its the max percent, I would expect it to output the winner- but it is outputting the last input every time, even when they have the least votes.

Answer (score 2):

1. You add the number of each candidates votes at the same time you calculate the percent vote for each candidate. You need to find the total votes first, then divide each candidates votes by the total
2. You are returning the max of a list of integers. Obviously you aren't going to get a string. You need some way to connect the number votes with the candidate.
3. Don't bother. You can try to figure out how many tabs you need to get the whole thing lined up, but from experience, it is basically impossible. You could separate them with commas and open it in excel as a csv, or you could just make the user figure out what number goes with what.

The other answer uses data tables, so I will take another, more vanilla and cool approach to getting what you want.

```
class candidate():

  def __init__(self, name, votes):
    self.name = name
    self.votes = int(votes)

  def percentvotes(self, total):
    self.percent = self.votes/total

  def printself(self, i):
    print('{}\t{}\t\t{}\t\t{}'.format(i, self.name, self.votes, self.percent))

def getinput():
  inp = input('Please enter your candidates name and votes')
  return inp
candidates = []
inp = getinput()
s = 0
while inp != '':
  s+=1
  candidates.append(candidate(*inp.split(" ")))
  inp = getinput()

for c in candidates:
  c.percentvotes(s)

candidates.sort(key = lambda x:-x.percent)

print('ID\tname\t\tvotes\t\tpercentage')
for i, c in enumerate(candidates):
  c.printself(i+1)
```

Comment: Hi, a couple of questions about this code. Where is the dictionary component?  is that the "lambda" section? Why name the variable "self" and what does that stand for?

Comment: @new.user I did not use a dictionary. I created a class called candidate, which has several attributes and functions which you needed. It might be beyond what you have learned yet. I think R.p.T did a great job of sticking with your way of doing it in his answer.

Comment: yeah unfortunately it did not work, keeps returnining the last input instead of the canidate with the most votes. Thanks @SamCraig

Answer (score -2):

I believe that this is the solution you are looking for. Just change the input statements in case you are using Python 2.x. Using Dataframe, the output will be exactly how you wanted.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Candidate", "Votes Received","Percentage of total votes"])
names=list()
votes=list()
while True:
    name = str(input("Enter Name of Candidate."))
    if name=='':
        break
    else:
        vote = int(input("Enter the number of votes obtained."))
        names.append(name)
        votes.append(vote)
s=sum(votes)
xx=(votes.index(max(votes)))
myArray = np.array(votes)
percent = myArray/s*100

for i in range(len(names)):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[names[i],votes[i],percent[i]]],columns=["Candidate", "Votes Received","Percentage of total votes"])
    df = pd.concat([df,df1], axis=0)

df.index = range(len(df.index))
print (df)
print ("Total votes = ",s)
print ("The man who won is ",names[xx])
```